# IF Statement not working in while loop PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to stop one part of a while loop from only running ONCE.

I have searched and an IF statement seems to be the only way

The only thing is,when i put IF statement in - it doesn't seem to DO the INSERT statement at all, so nothing is being inserted, it's as if it's stopping before insert statement. As you can see $inserted is declared outside the loop and then changed to true inside so it stops, but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Without it, it will loop each time the page is refreshed and insert into the database each refresh of the page, although i only need the INSERT statement to run once. I need it in the loop as that's where the information for the insert is.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Fix quotes, please.

Comment: It helps us to provide an answer to your question.

Comment: @u_mulder what do you mean?

Comment: You have several syntax errors in this example.

Comment: Do you see colors in your code? they're broken, fix'em.

Comment: Even after fixing the quotes, you seem to be trying to generate the form and insert the data with the same code. You do realize that the html is is run in the browser, and the PHP code runs on the server, right? Your form would submit to a separate PHP file to do the inserts.

Comment: OK so if i put in the php tags etc, difer from html and PHP, that will sort out the if statement? It's the if statement part that's the problem.. nothing prior to that.

Comment: Think about using two files, one to create the form, and another to process (insert) the data. The first sends the form to the browser. When the user submits the form, it calls the 2nd file which performs the inserts.

Comment: Make sure you are using an editor that has syntax highlighting.

Comment: hmm.. , What ? now every body will think i copied your code, get serious,  updating your code with my answer? lol . do you rely know what you are doing?

Comment: @SloanThrasher I want to display the form, and then do the insert? Is above incorrect?Is there a better way to do this? within the while loop, items are being displayed..thats why after i try to get the ID of ones displayed as this is what i need?

Comment: The purpose/function of this page is very unclear. You explanation makes no sense at all. Why do an insert when you seem to be displaying a list? Why would the insert be inside the loop? What is the purpose of the insert? Where is the data for the insert coming from?

Comment: Basically from displaying the list, (which is based on user preference) therefore, whats displayed for each user is different. what is displayed for the particular user, i need that information to go back into the database regarding what is being displayed for that exact user. If i put it outside the loop it does not work, it cannot get the 'ID' in which it can inside the loop. Hope this makes sense @SloanThrasher

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and then let us know what the errors are.  If it's not inserting, it could be an error within PDO that you need to know of.

```
    if (!$inserted) {
        $inserted = true;
        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT into UserRecipes (UserID, RecipeID, Displayed) VALUES (:UserID, :RecipeID, :Displayed) ");
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':UserID' => $UserID,
                ':MealID' => $MealID,
                ':Displayed' => $Displayed
            ));
        } catch (PDOException $p) {
            print $p;
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a basic flaw beyond the quotes. I think the OP thinks the PHP code for the insert will run after the html form code.

Comment: @SloanThrasher - I also agree.  I didn't realize it until I actually looked at the code itself.  However, if he DOES have an error with his SQL statement like he thinks, this will help him identify it.

Comment: Hi @webdevsoup, thanks for that. With that, it inserts into the database with refresh still, and also only inserts into the database 2 records out of 4. There are 4 items displayed(4 of which should be inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to fix your quotes were too bad

```
    <?php

$inserted=false;

while($dbRow=$dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) and ($cnt < $max))  
    {
     echo ''.$dbRow["Name"].'<br><img src="\"'.$dbRow["Picture"].' width="150" height="150" /><br><br>'.$dbRow["Instructions"].'

<form method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="MealID" value= "'.$dbRow['MealID'].'">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Complete" ></form>';

$cnt++;


$MealID=$dbRow["MealID"];
$Displayed = false;
if (!$inserted) {
$inserted=true;
$stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT into UserRecipes (UserID, RecipeID, Displayed) VALUES (:UserID, :RecipeID, :Displayed) "); 
$stmt->execute(array(
       ':UserID' => $UserID,
       ':MealID' => $MealID,
       ':Displayed' => $Displayed
        )); 
   }
    }


?>
```

let me hope i have not missed any thing

Comment: i did not copy this code but the owner update there code with mine - so i will not delete my answer and dont  downgrade it please

Comment: Sorry didn't know that wasn't allowed. This may sort out quotes..but doesn't help with IF statement issue.

Comment: i did the quotes , now configure your if s

Comment: i have done that, thank you very much but the IF statement is still not working.